# I want to call FCM manually to get token while it is null in android application

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, token, firebase-cloud-messaging

I wanna know that if there is solution to get FCM token while it's null? In other words, I want to call FCM manually to get token while it is null in Android application?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the token faster you have to use:

```
token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken("projectNumber","FCM");
```

instead of:

```
token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `getInstanceId()` instead of `getToken()`,its deprecated.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
                                String deviceToken = instanceIdResult.getToken();

                            }
                        });
                    }
                }).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get `null` when calling `FirebaseInstanceID.getToken()`, it means that the token hasn't been generated yet. There is no API to force generating the token *now*, so you'll have to instead monitor token generation.

To monitor token generation, create a class that derives from `com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId` and override its `onTokenRefresh()` method:

```
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    // Get updated InstanceID token.
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

    // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
    // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
    // Instance ID token to your app server.
    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
}
```

Note that both getting and monitoring the token are covered in the Firebase documentation on [accessing the registration token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/first-message#access_the_registration_token), which is where I got the above code sample from.

Comment: Thanks, I will check that